# How to calculate the time when robot moved from one position to another or to a some distance?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to know the travel time for my robot when he move from one position to another. So for example I wont to know the time needed that my robot move 10 m forwards. So I have a map ov the environment and my platform has IMU, laser, Kinect and encoders. So I do not do any navigation just driving the platform for example 20 m forwards and wont to know the time needed to complete that task. Any help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62757/how-to-calculate-the-time-when-robot-moved-from-one-position-to-another-or-to-a-some-distance?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-05-15**:
Are you driving yourself by hand? In that case, you'd anyways have inaccuracies in the measurements and you can just use a stopwatch instead of software.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-15**:
I need a software ROS solution and not a stopwatch. So I need to know the time when platforms move from one position in the map to other.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-15**:
Im not driving by my self. Im observing when someone else is driving it.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-05-15**:
You can read out the encoders to measure the travelled distance and run a timer in parallel?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-15**:
the encoders are drifted. So maybe better to use the pose, How to run  a ROS timer??

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-05-15**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Timers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just use the system clock, and subtract the start time from the end time.  In python

```
import time

start = time.clock()
# Do something
end = time.clock()

print end-start, 'seconds'
```

and in C++, use `gettimeofday()` or some similar function.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1